# Closing and reopening the application

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I know title of my question doesn’t make any sense. So what happened is I’ve run my app once. I stored current date in ‘NSUserDefaults’. I closed the app. Then the next day (by changing the date in system) I opened the app in simulator, did the same action again. And primarily stored Current date in ‘NSUserDefaults’ was also updated to today’s value.

Instead if I run the app again through Xcode. It returns values as expected. I just want to know the difference between these two operations. Running the app again and again makes the app work properly. But running once and reopening and using it again doesn’t make it happen. Why is this!!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the two operations you are performing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing the point that the operations you're doing are in the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in your `AppDelegate`. This method gets called when your app launches. Then if you press the home button and reopen the app, this method would not get called because the app is in inactive state, but the method -`applicationWillEnterForeground` is called. If you kill the app (or the OS kills it) and open it again `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called again.

Comment: So when the app launches '-applicationWillEnterForeground’ will not be called. Is that it?

Comment: When it launches for the first time, `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions-` is called, when is resumed `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called. Just put breakpoints and debug.. You can also read the docs about the application lifecycle...

Comment: Is there a way I can respond to `applicationWillEnterForeground` from the ViewController? Or is there a version of this for view controllers, rather than the entire application?